# Virtual Machines Communication Path

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, trace

I've Windows OS as my host machine and I'm running two guest VMs on virtualbox. I've setup 2 interfaces on both VMs; NAT and host-based. I can communicate between the guest and host OS easily. Just out of curiosity, I want to know what path it takes for communication between two VMs.

1. `VM <-> VM`
2. `VM -> Windows -> VM`

It should take the 2nd path, but I'm asking anyways just for sake of clarity.

Comment: Yes, option 2 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**IP_Engr**, 
I also have a host on Windows7 and several VM Window based inside VirtualBox.
On host computer I have 2 network cards, both set up for every machine like this:

[image]

I have shared folders on all 3 components (host + 2 VMs) and I can file transfer both your ways:

1. `VM <-> VM`
2. `VM -> Windows -> VM`

*If this fits better for you, then try this setup, if not, I'll edit the answer with your scenario and edit this response.*

Comment: I think the snapshot is from guest VMs? (not the host)
Also, you have set up a bridge. I'm using one adapter as host-based and other as NAT (for internet). Thanks :)

Comment: it's from [VirtualBox -> Settings -> Network] of one of the virtual machines